# Automatically abort a "failed" git rebase?

Tags: git

As part of a Git (1.7.9.5) `post-update` hook, I want (inter alia) to delete a commit in a branch checked out in the working tree.  This works great with:

```
git rebase --onto $commit^ $commit $branch
```

But if the changes in the commits `$commit..$branch` build upon the changes in `$commit`, there is the potential for the deletion to fail.  In this case, I don't want to leave the working tree in the state where the user has to intervene, and instead fail loudly.

I noticed that when a rebase succeeds cleanly, `git rebase` returns an exit code of 0, while if it encounters an unresolvable merge conflict, it returns 1.

Is there an option that I missed to signal `git rebase` that it should automatically abort a failed rebase, or do I need to use something like `git rebase […] || git rebase --abort`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `||` (or something equivalent).

(I'm not skipping over commits in my own rebase, but i have a Python script to do en-masse rebasing after fetching.  I use the exit status of a non-interactive `git rebase` to determine whether to run `git rebase --abort`.)